# How to create Kibana Index Pattern in Python

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In Python there are methods for creating index template, index. Does anyone knows which method is used to create Index Pattern ?

es.indices.put_index_template()  - creating index template

es.indices.create()              - creating index

es.indices.??????()

Comment: There is a trick here, I myself found the API from kibana UI, try to see XHR when you create an index pattern in kibana

Comment: Yes, same such method doesn't exist. I used this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.16/index-patterns-api-create.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Kibana rest api interface...
as outlined here

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/api.html

to create / update etc Kibana Index patterns